# JSON: How to display API values?

Tags: javascript, json, linkedin-api

I'm trying to display the values of a JSON, coming from a LinkedIn API specifically IN.API.Profile(), I am able to get to output the values by using **"alert(JSON.stringify(result));"**, however I'm trying to put the api values to their corresponding places, (firstName = firstName label etc...)

When the button is clicked the firstName should display in the 1st label and so on and so forth.
How can I accomplish this?

Code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
  api_key: XXXXXXXXXXX
  authorize: true
  onLoad: getProfileData
</script>

<script>
   function getProfileData() {
    IN.API.Profile("me")
      .fields(["firstName", "lastName", "headline", "summary"])
      .result(function(result) {
     alert(JSON.stringify(result));
     //document.write(me.fields.firstName).value = firstName;
      });
  }

  </script>

  </head>
  <body>  

  <input  id="firstName">
  <input id="lastName">
  <input id="headline">
  <input id="summary">
  <button id="Add" onclick="getProfileData()">Add Boss</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

***Update...........................................................***

Sir by element you mean (firstName, lastName, etc...)? this what I did sir but it promps an error that says getProfileData undefined

```
function getProfileData() {
     .fields(["firstName", "lastName", "headline", "summary"])
     .result(function (result) {
    for (var fields in fields(result)) {
        document.getElementById("firstName").value = result[0];
        document.getElementById("lastName").value = result[1];
        document.getElementById("headline").value = result[2];
        document.getElementById("summary").value = result[3];  
    }
})
}
```

Comment: You should parse the result not stringify it

Comment: `JSON.stringify(result)` is wrong, you would have to destringify / parse it. The `stringify` function does convert a javascript object to JSON, you need the opposite.

Comment: @RononDex what do you mean by opposite sir? can you be more specific, I would love to learn how to do it

Comment: @SOS Your method already receives a Javascript array, no need to use JSON.

Comment: @RononDex Sir can you provide an example so that it can guide me and I can use it as basis, this is my first time using LinkedIn API's and my second time dealing with API's still a newbie but willing to learn

Comment: @SOS, you dont have to call me sir ;). You only need to stringify if you want to send data to a Web-API (interface). Check Kroltans answer ;). EDIT: With opposite I meant you need to convert JSON to javascript, and not javascript to JSON, like you are doing it right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.result()` passes a JavaScript array to the function gave, no need to parse or stringify it as JSON. If you want to set each field's value from that function, you'd need something like this:

```
.result(function (result) {
    for (var key in result) {
        document.getElementById(key).value = result[key];
    }
})
```

Comment: sir I tried it and it prompts an error, I've updated the code sir

Comment: @SOS Well, `Object.keys` isn't yet implemented everywhere. I've edited the answer.

Comment: sir can I asked what is the .result method called?is it parsing or something? so I can study it further, because it still prompts an error that says Object is not a function pertaining to the line where for(var key in result) is placed